# Looping a carousel made with translate3d

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a carousel that has drag option made with `translate3d`. Taking into consideration that is use `translate3d` to go to the next slide, i end up translating to the end of the carousel. Can you help me finding a solution?

Next slide logic:

```
    goNext() {
    this.carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${-(++this.elementIndex * this.album.clientWidth)}px,0,0);
    }
```

When i get to the end of the carousel:[image]
I know that i can translate to 0 at the end but i want on the last slide to keep the drag option and to be able to drag to the first slide looking like is the next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is:

- place a clone of last image to the beginnig of carousel and first image to the end of carousel (during initialization).

  `5 [1 2 3 4 5] 1`
- when user clicks "next" at the last slide you should switch it to the very first slide (cloned "5") without animation, and then you can transform it to "1" with animation

  `1)  5  1  2  3  4 [5] 1`

  `2) [5] 1  2  3  4  5  1`

  `3)  5 [1] 2  3  4  5  1`